# Sending images in web service from iPhone using HTTP POST

Tags: iphone, web-services

I need to send the images to the server. Images should be converted as byte array. How to convert image into byte array and send it in a web service?

Comment: Did you mean web service or web server?

Answer (score 2):

Use either `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`
which will return `NSData*`.

And set your body `content-type` as `image/jpg` or `image/png`

Comment: If it's a web service then the content-type will be `text/xml`; unless of course the OP meant Web Server, and not Web Service...

Comment: Images will be sent as part of web service (http post).. Is it better to append the image directly or do we need to encode/convert into some other format for sending in a web service?

Comment: What is the preferred technology for backend (web service) implementation? It needs to return the image as such, since we directly send the image in .png format.